# Calling Oracle PL SQL Function from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, oracle, excel, plsql

I am trying to call PL SQL function from excel vba. When i execute it on ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER it runs perfectly. But when i try to run same from excel vba it gives me following error.

[image]

Please have a look at following code snippet.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim con As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim cmd As Object
    Dim sQuery As String
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

    strcon = "Provider=OraOledb.Oracle;Data Source=10.1.2.238:1521/oracle.MultiActTrade.LOCAL; User ID=; Password=;Persist Security Info=True"
    con.Open strcon

    sQuery = "SELECT * FROM TABLE(MA_DWM_AVG(TO_CHAR('L48D88-S-IN'),TO_NUMBER(2),TO_NUMBER(11),TO_NUMBER(40)))"
    cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    cmd.CommandText = sQuery
    Set rs = cmd.Execute()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
End Sub
```

Even after using sQuery as follows error remains as it is. The variables data types are already taken care very well. No type mismatch is there.

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE(MA_DWM_AVG('L48D88-S-IN',2,11,40))
```

Following is the function code where i am facing an error. Function code is very big so giving the required snippet only.

```sql
create or replace function MA_DWM_AVG(FID IN VARCHAR, CHOICE INT, PERIOD1 INT,PERIOD2 INT)
return TEMP_NESTED as

 --to create a seperate transcion for the function we have created.
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  V_RET TEMP_NESTED;

begin
--TRUNCATING GTT TABLE USED IN A FUNCTION
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE GTT_DWM_STATS';
--IF DAILTY STATISTICS ARE NEEDED THEN CHOICE=1
--We calculate rownumber,fs_perm_sec_id, date ,closing value its avearages    for 2 periods, open price, high price for the day, low price for the day

--weekly statistics are allculated if choice=2
IF CHOICE =2 AND PERIOD1<>0 AND PERIOD2<>0 THEN
--First we calculate rownumber,fs_perm_sec_id, week end date, Closing price and its average for 2 periods


INSERT INTO GTT_DWM_STATS(ROWNUMBER,FID,CLOSINGDATE,PRICE_CLOSE,MOVINGAVERAGE_PERIOD1,MOVINGAVERAGE_PERIOD2) 
    SELECT ROWNUM,FS_PERM_SEC_ID,"DATE",PPRICE,
        CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(PPRICE) OVER (ORDER BY "DATE" DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND PERIOD1-1 FOLLOWING) >= PERIOD1
        THEN AVG(PPRICE) OVER (ORDER BY "DATE" DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND PERIOD1-1 FOLLOWING)
        ELSE NULL
        END AS "Moving Average Period 1",
        CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(PPRICE) OVER (ORDER BY "DATE" DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND PERIOD2-1 FOLLOWING) >= PERIOD2
        THEN AVG(PPRICE) OVER (ORDER BY "DATE" DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND PERIOD2-1 FOLLOWING)
        ELSE NULL
        END AS "Moving Average Period 2"
        FROM(
                SELECT FS_PERM_SEC_ID,"DATE",P_PRICE AS PPRICE,P_VOLUME,
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (TO_CHAR("DATE",'D') >= AVG(TO_CHAR("DATE",'D')) OVER (order by "DATE" DESC rows between 1 preceding and current row) and ROWNUM>=1) 
                            or TO_CHAR("DATE",'D')=6
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END AS WEEKFLAG
                FROM FP_BASIC_BD WHERE FS_PERM_SEC_ID=FID AND P_VOLUME<>0 ORDER BY "DATE" DESC) WHERE WEEKFLAG=1;
--get week start date
--line 89 is here
UPDATE GTT_DWM_STATS 
    SET STARTDATE = 
        (SELECT "DATE" FROM FP_BASIC_BD  WHERE FP_BASIC_BD.FS_PERM_SEC_ID=FID AND FP_BASIC_BD."DATE">=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE(GTT_DWM_STATS.CLOSINGDATE,'DD-MON-YY'), 'IW'),'DD-MON-YY') AND P_VOLUME<>0 AND ROWNUM=1) 
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FP_BASIC_BD."DATE" FROM FP_BASIC_BD WHERE FP_BASIC_BD."DATE"=GTT_DWM_STATS.CLOSINGDATE );
--get opening price for the week
UPDATE GTT_DWM_STATS
    SET PRICE_OPEN = 
        (SELECT FP_BASIC_BD.P_PRICE_OPEN FROM FP_BASIC_BD WHERE FP_BASIC_BD.FS_PERM_SEC_ID=GTT_DWM_STATS.FID AND FP_BASIC_BD."DATE"=GTT_DWM_STATS.STARTDATE);
--get high value of p_price_high for week's duration
UPDATE GTT_DWM_STATS 
    SET PRICE_HIGH= 
        (SELECT MAX(P_PRICE_HIGH) FROM FP_BASIC_BD WHERE FP_BASIC_BD.FS_PERM_SEC_ID=FID AND FP_BASIC_BD."DATE" BETWEEN GTT_DWM_STATS.STARTDATE AND GTT_DWM_STATS.CLOSINGDATE)
        WHERE EXISTS(SELECT P_PRICE_HIGH FROM FP_BASIC_BD WHERE FP_BASIC_BD.FS_PERM_SEC_ID=GTT_DWM_STATS.FID);
--get low value of p_price_low for week's duration
UPDATE GTT_DWM_STATS 
    SET PRICE_LOW= 
        (SELECT MIN(P_PRICE_LOW) FROM FP_BASIC_BD WHERE FP_BASIC_BD.FS_PERM_SEC_ID=FID AND FP_BASIC_BD."DATE" BETWEEN GTT_DWM_STATS.STARTDATE AND GTT_DWM_STATS.CLOSINGDATE) WHERE EXISTS(SELECT P_PRICE_LOW FROM FP_BASIC_BD WHERE FP_BASIC_BD.FS_PERM_SEC_ID=GTT_DWM_STATS.FID);


END IF;


--get the GTT values into table derived from object type and return it.
select 
    cast(
    multiset(

                select * from GTT_DWM_STATS WHERE GTT_DWM_STATS.FID=FID ORDER BY CLOSINGDATE DESC

             )as TEMP_NESTED) into v_ret from dual;

   COMMIT;
   return V_RET;

end MA_DWM_AVG;
```

You can also refer the DDL for global temporary table which is as follows.

```sql
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "MA_FACTSET"."GTT_DWM_STATS" 
(   "ROWNUMBER" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "FID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "CLOSINGDATE" DATE, 
    "PRICE_CLOSE" FLOAT(126), 
    "MOVINGAVERAGE_PERIOD1" FLOAT(126), 
    "MOVINGAVERAGE_PERIOD2" FLOAT(126), 
    "STARTDATE" DATE, 
    "PRICE_OPEN" FLOAT(126), 
    "PRICE_HIGH" FLOAT(126), 
    "PRICE_LOW" FLOAT(126)
   ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;
```

**Please don't suggest me to use function as a procedure. Because function is using a Global Temporary Table and at the end it returns that complete table. So using it as a function compulsory.**

Comment: What's on line 89 of your PL/SQL function?

Comment: Please show us the code of function MA_DWM_AVG

Comment: Both the things are provided. Please provide your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your work with dates is totally incorrect. It's hard to point exact place because there are some potential places. I'll explain what's wrong with this piece of code (it is taken from your "line 89" statement):

```
... FP_BASIC_BD."DATE">=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE(GTT_DWM_STATS.CLOSINGDATE,'DD-MON-YY'), 'IW'),'DD-MON-YY') ...
```

`GTT_DWM_STATS.CLOSINGDATE` has date format (according to your DDL statement). But `to_date` function takes a string as a first parameter. In this place, Oracle does the following:

- implicitly converts date to string (using session's format)
- then `to_date` function tries to convert it back into a date, treating the string as a date written in `'DD-MON-YY'` format
- then `trunc` truncates the date
- then `to_char` converts it again into a string, and than you compare your string with the date (I guess) `FP_BASIC_BD."DATE"`
- if `FP_BASIC_BD."DATE"` is a date, Oracle converts implicitly the result of expression to the right of equal sign again into a date
- or if `FP_BASIC_BD."DATE"` is a string, Oracle compares strings acording to rules of a string comparison.

What you need here is to get rid of all unnecessary transformations:

```
FP_BASIC_BD."DATE" >= TRUNC(GTT_DWM_STATS.CLOSINGDATE, 'IW')
```

And after that you have to check carefully all other statements where you are working with dates. If a function takes a date as input parameter, you have to pass a date, if a function takes a string - pass a string. The same with comparisons: compare a string with a string and a date with a date.

Comment: Thanks a lot fr the help. And the explanation is very much outstanding.

Comment: Some more notes: Commit is not necessary, the oleDB performs commit automatically after each statement by default. The you may prefer to return a RefCursor instead of a table of object.