# Converting timestamp to date in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to convert a given timestamp in such format: `2019-04-08 00:00:00.0` to a date in this format: `2019-04-08`.

I have already tried using:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2019-04-20 00:00:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
```

But I got prompted with:

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input
>   string

Comment: Is this timestamp a string (text), or is it an actual Oracle timestamp?

Comment: Typically the confusion around dates and timestamps in Oracle comes from not realising that these are native datatypes which are stored in an internal binary format and only given convenient human-readable formats when required for display purposes. The fun starts when developers assume that something like `'2019-04-20 00:00:00.0'` is an actual Oracle timestamp when it's really just a string. To convert an actual `timestamp` to an actual `date` you would just use `cast` as in Littlefoot's answer, but I suspect that is not the situation you are facing here.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51492266/2141278

Answer (score 3):

I think you may have some conceptual misunderstanding about how the TO_DATE function works, and also about how dates are processed by the DBMS.

`YYY-MM-DD` does not match the format of the actual string you're importing (`2019-04-20 00:00:00.0`) That's what the error is telling you. You must tell the TO_DATE function what to expect in the date string you *input* into it. You do that by means of the format string. if you don't specify a format string which matches the format you're actually going to supply, then the function will fail to process the string.

Next, you say you want to convert it "to a date in this format"...but this does not entirely make sense. TO_DATE converts a string into a variable of type `DATETIME` - i.e. a date object. A date object does not not exist in any particular format, it exists as an object. Internally it will store the date information in a way which is independent of any human-readable date format. The format relates entirely to the *presentation* of the date when seen as a *string*. Once you have a date object, you can then *output* the date in a particular format if you want to a human to be able to read it in the style that their culture is familiar with.

So, firstly to import your date string correctly as a date object, you can use an accurate format string, an also use TO_TIMESTAMP instead of TO_DATE so that it captures the sub-seconds value:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-04-20 00:00:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF5') from dual;
```

If you run this in a console the SELECT will then automatically re-format that date object (the result of the TO_DATE function) into the default date format configured in your server / session.

However if you actually want to see it on screen in a particular format, you can explicitly say so - a sensible way is using the TO_CHAR function:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMPT('2019-04-20 00:00:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF5'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
```

The full list of format specifiers can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) (and in other places online as well).

Live demo of the above here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=619d918ea73953e11b3150c6b560112c

Comment: heh; I rethought my original comment (hence I deleted it) because your query seemed to work on 18c. However, you're using `sssss` for the subseconds, but it should actually be `ff5`. E.g. `SELECT TO_DATE('2019-04-20 00:00:01.12345','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.SSSSS') from dual;` fails with `ORA-01836: hour conflicts with seconds in day`; it only appears to work because the OP's date-string had 0's for the seconds.

Comment: @Boneist you are indeed correct again. See edit - much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input is actual text, and not a real timestamp, you could try just truncating the text before you call `TO_DATE`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT '2019-04-20 00:00:00.0' AS ts FROM dual
)

SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTR(ts, 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM cte;
```

If your input is an actual Oracle timestamp, and you want to convert it to a date, then you may use `CAST`:

```
SELECT CAST(ts AS DATE) dt
FROM cte;
```

Comment: I'd go with `trunc(ts)` rather than the cast, since the cast will leave the time element present (albeit without the subseconds), or even `to_char(ts, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Comment: @Boneist I'll wait for feedback from the OP before acting on your comment, but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Would **CAST** do any good?

I'm setting date format so that it displays *time* component, although it is 00:00:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select cast(timestamp '2019-04-20 00:00:00.0' as date) result from dual;

RESULT
-------------------
20.04.2019 00:00:00
```

Another format (without time component):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select cast(timestamp '2019-04-20 00:00:00.0' as date) result from dual;

RESULT
----------
20.04.2019

SQL>
```

Or, using `TO_CHAR` function (so that session's date format doesn't matter):

```
SQL> select to_char(timestamp '2019-04-20 00:00:00.0', 'dd.mm.yyyy') result from dual;

RESULT
----------
20.04.2019

SQL>
```

Comment: if you use to_char, why not just to_char on the timestamp itself, rather than casting it first?

Comment: That's a good question, @Boneist. No particular reason, perhaps an excuse or two - I had to go offline and copy/pasted the same code and slightly modified it, without thinking too much about what I was doing. I fixed it; thank you for the comment.